# Convert css from html style tag into inline css

Tags: html, css

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html >
        <head>
            <style>

    .accordion section:target { background:#FFF; padding:10px;}
    .accordion section:target h2 a{ color:#333; padding:0;}
    .accordion section:target p {display:block;}
    .accordion section{ float:left; overflow:hidden; color:#333; cursor:pointer; background: #333; margin:3px; width:100%; height:40px; }
    .accordion section p { display:none; }
    .vertical :target{ height:250px; width:97%; }


    </style>

        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>CSS3 Only Accordion Examples</h1>


            <div style="width:830px; overflow:hidden; margin:10px auto; color:#474747; background:#414141; padding:10px;" class="accordion vertical">
              <section id="vertabout" target=" background:#FFF; padding:10px;">
                  <h2 style=" position:relative; left:0; top:-15px; "><a style="padding:8px 10px;display:block; font-size:16px; font-weight:normal;color:#eee; text-decoration:none;" href="#vertabout">About Us</a></h2>
                  <p>fggfdgasf</p>
              </section>
              <section id="vertservices">
                  <h2 style=" position:relative; left:0; top:-15px; "><a style="padding:8px 10px;display:block; font-size:16px; font-weight:normal;color:#eee; text-decoration:none;" href="#vertservices">Services</a></h2>
                  <p>dcsadsc</p>
              </section>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

How to convert the codes inside style tags into inline css?
So that it can be send through email attachments as for proper viewing of the  attachments only inline css are needed for email.

Comment: What programming language? Whats the setup of the project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What tools to automatically inline CSS style to create email HTML code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791070/what-tools-to-automatically-inline-css-style-to-create-email-html-code)

Answer (score 0):

Zurb inliner does this. Have a look at http://zurb.com/ink/inliner.php