# How to extract html style tag into css

Tags: html, css, tags, styles

I'm trying to extract automatically the part of the tag's style from div html. I have 100 style combinations, so doing it manually is not possible.
This is the path html style tags --> css

```css
.rule1 { 
  background-color: rgb(196, 0, 143);
}

.rule { 
  background-color: rgb(230, 176, 18);
}
```

```html
<div class="line line--big line--active" role="button" 
   style="background: rgb(196, 0, 143) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; color: white; opacity: 1;"><span>1</span></div>
<div class="line line--big line--active" role="button"
   style="background: rgb(230, 176, 18) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; color: white; opacity: 1;"><span>5</span></div>
```

**Attention:** this question is not duplicate because i don't have in my code the **style tag.**
I already searched for other answers but they
zurb link is down now
http://zurb.com/ink/inliner.php
here you need the style tag:
[JavaScript Regex to Extract Text from Style HTML Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124649/javascript-regex-to-extract-text-from-style-html-tags) and also here:
[Convert css from html style tag into inline css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606101/convert-css-from-html-style-tag-into-inline-css)

Comment: You want to remove the style attribute from the divs of a document or your html is still a string?

Comment: I want to remove the style from the html. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: you want to remove or extract html style tag into css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1: extractCSS - Online CSS Extractor**

extractCSS is a JavaScript library and an online tool that lets you extract element ID, class and inline styles from HTML document and output them as CSS.

**Note :**
Not exactly what you are looking for but if you don't mind copying and pasting your HTML, try this. Not too many features but it does the job!

http://extractcss.com/

https://github.com/peterlazzarino/Inline-CSS-Extractor

**Method 2 : using Jquery :**

You can use some JS/JQuery code to extract the styles, clear them, give elements an ID and add up css. Check this example, you may extend it further.

**HTML:**

```
<style></style>
<div style="background-color: red; height:300px; width:200px;">
<a style="font-weight: bold">Link</a>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;
    var css = "";
    $("div,a").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("id","st-"+i);
        css += "#"+$(this).attr("id")+"{"+$(this).attr("style")+"}";
        $(this).removeAttr("style");
        i++;
    });
    $("style").html(css);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Priya. This solution give my an unique 1 css class for the 2 style tags. The thing i wanted is x unique css classes for each unique x style tags.  But with a bit of notepad++ and excel i think i could manage.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use simplehtmldom to extract this :

---

For

```
<style>
...
</style>
```

Use :

```
$css = $html->find('style')->innertext;
```

---

For

```
<div style="background:blue; color:white;"></div>
```

Use :

```
$css = $html->find('div[style]')->style;
```

---

If there's more than one `div` with `style` atribute or more than one `<style>`, you can use a `foreach` to loop between them.

---

To parse styles :

in PHP :

```php
$s = 'background:blue; color:white;';

$results = [];
$styles = explode(';', $s);

foreach ($styles as $style) {
    $properties = explode(':', $style);
    if (2 === count($properties)) {
        $results[trim($properties[0])] = trim($properties[1]);
    }
}

var_dump($results);
```

in JS

```js
let s = 'background:blue; color:white;';

let results = {};
let styles = s.split(";");

for (let style in styles) {
    let properties = styles[style].split(":");
  if (properties.length === 2) {
    results[properties[0].trim()] = properties[1].trim();
  }
}

console.log(results);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zyfhtwj2/